# Why is my object being split from char to char?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When I use

> console.log(Object.values(params))

The console log in node shows this:

> [ '[',   '"',   'i',   'd',   '"',   ',',   '"',   'N',   'o',   'm', 
>   'e',   '"',   ',',   '"',   'T',   'i',   'p',   'o',   'P',  ...

The console log on browser shows the data normally but when sending to the backend it looks like it's being split.

This is the code on backend:

```
_server.get(`/${Model.entity}/update`, (req, res) => {        
    Model.updateDefault(req.query.params)
})

  updateDefault(table, params) {        
    console.log(Object.values(params))    
  }
```

Comment: params is a **string** - `Object.values` of a string is each character - perhaps you want `Object.values(JSON.parse(params))`

Comment: OMG! Thanks! I'm trying to solve this in like 2 hours

Comment: Also node that since this is an Array, `Object.values` is also not need., just `JSON.parse(params)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Bravo. 
I have solve this using Object.assign to change the object reference.

It seems that redux doesn't notice the store change if we only change a part of the object. So the way to do it is by changing the object reference through:

```
 case Actions.SEARCH_CEP:
        {
            let newData = {     
                    Endereco:   action.payload.logradouro ?  action.payload.logradouro : '',
                    Bairro:     action.payload.bairro ?  action.payload.bairro : '',
                    Uf:         action.payload.uf ?  action.payload.uf : '',
                    Cidade:     action.payload.localidade ?  action.payload.localidade : '' 
            }
            Object.assign(state.data, newData)

            return {
                ...state,
                data: { 
                    ...state.data                   
                }
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use `Object.values()` with string it will give you all the values like this

```js
let str = 'Hello'
console.log(Object.values(str));
console.log(Object.keys(str));
```

Here string is also having index and value so it will give you all the values and 
`Object.keys(str)` will give you all the index values.

**When to use `Object.values()`, `Object.keys()` , `Object.entries()`**

Example -

```js
let obj = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 45,
  country: 'ABC'
}
console.log(Object.values(obj))
console.log(Object.keys(obj))
console.log(Object.entries(obj));
```